# Sorting by date

Tags: php, mysql

I am working on a search tool using PHP, which is retrieving data from a database. It works, but now I would like to sort the results by the newest date. `created` is the name of the column that stores the database time stamp.

Here is the code I have:

```
$res = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM book WHERE MATCH
(title,cat_number,isbn,issn,created,subject) AGAINST ('$q' $mode) LIMIT 50", $db);

$list = array();
while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($res))
{
    $list[] = $row;
}
mysql_free_result($res);
```

Comment: **Heads up!**  PHP is *deprecating and removing* the `mysql_` family of functions in a future version. Please take this opportunity to switch to [PDO](http://php.net/book.pdo) or [mysqli](http://php.net/book.mysqli).

Comment: Check limitations of timestamp: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/datetime.html

Answer (score 2):

Add `ORDER BY created DESC` to your SQL statement.

Comment: It still did not work. For some reason it is not sorting it by created. Any other ideas?

Answer (score 1):

You can update your query to look like this:

```
$res = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM book WHERE MATCH (title,cat_number,isbn,issn,created,subject) AGAINST ('$q' $mode) ORDER BY created DESC LIMIT 50", $db);
```

On another note, you should be using mysqli or PDO over mysql commands, as mysql commands are now deprecated.

Comment: It still did not work. For some reason it is not sorting it by created. Any other ideas?

Comment: Are you running in boolean mode?  Check out this fiddle, which sorts properly: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/53847/1

Also, what data type is the created column?

Comment: Yes, I am running it in boolean mode. The type of data in the created colum is timestamp assigned by the database.

Comment: Have you manually checked the rows in the database to verify the values of created?  Can you provide some rows where this is not working properly?